# Условие постановки тире

Tags: пунктуация, тире, сложное-предложение

Всю голову сломала, может, вы подскажете, почему здесь ставится тире?
**Ноты Моцарта именно сошли с бумаги — они парят в пространстве, их слышит слепой скрипач.**

Я все-таки больше склоняюсь к тому, что это, скорее, авторский знак, либо данное тире служит разграничителем двух предложений, т. е говорит нам, что в этом месте нужно сделать паузу.
Пожалуйста, объясните .

Answer (score 3):

***(1) Ноты Моцарта именно сошли с бумаги — (2) они парят в пространстве, (3)их слышит слепой скрипач.***

**Это сложное предложение с бессоюзной связью,** которое с помощью тире делится на две части. Тире соответствует паузе в устной речи.

**Предложения 2 и 3 поясняют, раскрывают содержание предложения 1.** Обычно пояснительные отношения обозначаются двоеточием, то в данном случае вместо двоеточия используется тире. Интонационно это соответствует меньшей паузе, чем в случае двоеточия.

Предложения 2 и 3  однородные, между ними ставится запятая.

**Тире здесь не авторский знак, оно соответствует правилам:**

Полный академический справочник под ред. Лопатина (ПАС) http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=135#pp135

Примечание 2. **В бессоюзном сложном предложении при обозначении пояснения,** причины, обоснования, изъяснения **допустимо употребление тире вместо двоеточия** (особенно в художественной литературе и в публицистике).